# How to write getText() from the below code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, gettext, xpath-1.0

[In the below image, there is an **h1 tag**.  Text says, your policy number is ******. Here, Every-time when i run a new test-case, policy number will change. To get that policy number in **testng** output. What i need to use the code. I mean how can i getText()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35cF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the element by its xpath and then get the text from it.
You can do it like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='columns large-8']//h1[@class='fontFamily-1']")).getText()
```